# Execute API call when app is in background and user just connected to internet

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

In my app users perform quizzes. Results of those are sent to the server. But when users are not connected to internet I keep the result in local database. When user gets connected, I send results to server. Let, user performed 3 quizzes in offline and my local DB looks like:

```
+-------+-----------+----------+
| marks | chapterID | dateTime |
+-------+-----------+----------+
| 32.5  |     32    | 02-02-16 |
+-------+-----------+----------+
| 39.0  |     35    | 02-02-16 |
+-------+-----------+----------+
| 33.0  |     36    | 02-02-16 |
+-------+-----------+----------+
```

And when user gets connected (even my app is not running), I execute these:

```
www.xyz.com/api/stoer_marks?user_id=4323&chap_id=32&marks=32.5&date_time=02-02-16
www.xyz.com/api/stoer_marks?user_id=4323&chap_id=35&marks=39.0&date_time=02-02-16
www.xyz.com/api/stoer_marks?user_id=4323&chap_id=36&marks=33.0&date_time=02-02-16
```

So, that is my plan. My Android app does this with `Broadcast Receiver` but what in iOS? I searched Google and found Silent Push Notifications section of [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial) or [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) maybe my solution, but I'm confused as beginner in iOS. Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: iOS apps can't do this. There is no equivalent of listening while in the background for the connection change, nor is any real background execution, and push notification would only work if at the time the push is sent, there happens to be connectivity at that moment. There is some  limited background capabilities, but not for what you want to do.

Comment: Then is it possible to set a counter tick (while app not running) that checks connection every x minutes?

Comment: Also please tell me will [this example](https://gist.github.com/RameshRM/8ca0a1be512520a5240e) work when app is not running

Comment: A counter tick would only work while the app is in the foreground. Nothing can work when the app is not running because its not running. There is foreground, background and terminated states, I think what you are calling not running you mean background.

Comment: The background fetch functionality doesn't run when you specify, it runs when the OS decides to run it. It could perhaps be "good enough" for your purposes but its not under your control, its under the OS's control.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this that I know of. However, you could:

- Use background uploads. This way, iOS will perform the upload for you whenever it can (and notify you when this is done).
- Rely on background fetch. This will call your app in the background whenever iOS feels like it. There's no guarantee (as iOS makes the decision to call the app based on quite a few criteria), and there can be quite a delay.

Note also that as you are making changes server side, you should not use a `GET` request, but rather a `POST`, `PUT` or `PATCH`. You should also make sure that your server-side script can properly handle out-of-order updates, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to depend on Background Fetch.

- Silent push notification wan't work when your app is not running.
- Execute your code in background fetch and send your data to server. And it's better to use POST and PUT request for this.